# Sorting a collection in a generic method in Java 8

Tags: java, sorting, generics, java-8

The following method performs ordering.

```
public List<Comparator<Entity>> sort(Map<String, String> map) {
    List<Comparator<Entity>> list = new ArrayList<Comparator<Entity>>();

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        boolean sortOrder = entry.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("asc");

        switch (entry.getKey()) {
            case "id":
                list.add(sortOrder ? Comparator.comparing(Entity::getId) : Comparator.comparing(Entity::getId, Comparator.reverseOrder()));
                break;
            case "size":
                list.add(sortOrder ? Comparator.comparing(Entity::getSize) : Comparator.comparing(Entity::getSize, Comparator.reverseOrder()));
                //break;
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

The list being returned by the above method is used in the following way.

```
// map is initialized somewhere based on client's interactions with sorting.
// Based on client's interactions, map may be empty or it may contain one or more ordering fields.

if (MapUtils.isNotEmpty(map)) {  // map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

    List<Comparator<Entity>> comparators = sort(map);
    Comparator<Entity> comparator = comparators.remove(0);

    for (Comparator<Entity> c : comparators) {
        comparator = comparator.thenComparing(c);
    }

    list = list.stream().sorted(comparator).collect(Collectors.toList());
} else {
    // This is the default ordering.
    list = list.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Entity::getId).reversed()).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

`Entity` contains two fields named `id` of type `Integer` and `size` of type `BigDecimal` and `list` is a type of `List<Entity>`.

Since there are several other classes having the same fields with the same datatypes, I want this method to be generic so that it has to be defined only once like so,

```
public <T extends Object> List<Comparator<T>> sort(Map<String, String> map, Class<T> clazz) {
    List<Comparator<T>> list = new ArrayList<Comparator<T>>();

    // Sorting logic.

    return list;
}
```

But doing so, expressions like `T::getId` will not compile as obvious, since the generic type parameter `T` evaluates to `Object`.

Is there a way to code sorting without knowing the actual class type so that this method can be prevented from being repeated everywhere, when it is needed?

Comment: There's a way (and it's not too different from what you have), but I have to ask:  why are you returning a `List<Comparator<T>>`?  Wouldn't you want a `List<T>` instead?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have each class know how to sort itself?

Comment: @Makoto : It should function in any way whether it is a `List<Comparator<T>>` or `List<T>`.

Comment: @npinti : The method has to be defined for each class separately for that.

Comment: What I'm getting at is that the elements of your list don't make sense.  Are you returning a list of comparators, or a list of entities?

Comment: @Makoto : The method currently returns a list of `Comparator<Entity>`, not entities themselves

Comment: Since `Map`s don’t need to have a defined order, there is no point in iterating over a `Map` and creating a `List` as it’s still unclear what order the elements of the result list will have.

Comment: It still doesn't make a lick of sense to return a list of comparators (instead of a sorted list of entities), but I'll ask one more clarifying question:  how is this list actually used?  I get the feeling you're doing entirely too much work here, but I want to be sure of that.

Comment: @Holger : The `Map` is created using `LinkedHashMap<String, String>`.

Comment: @Makoto - typically, a map of request parameters, e.g. `/search?q=cat&sort=id_asc,size_desc`

Comment: @Tiny: but that’s nothing, this method can enforce. This also implies that at the point, when the `LinkedHashMap` is created and populated, there is already a source having a defined order. Then, why not process that source instead of filling and traversing a `Map`…

Comment: @Holger - the map could come from an underlying layer...

Comment: @Holger : It is used in a Java EE application where `LinkedHashMap` is initialized in a  managed bean with an appropriate scope.

Comment: @Makoto : Edited the question to reflect how a list of comparators is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way, without having to rely on reflection magic, is to introduce a common interface for all the types having the same fields with the same datatypes as `Entity`.

Consider the following `IdSize` interface with the following `Entity`.

```
interface IdSize {
    Integer getId();
    BigDecimal getSize();
}

class Entity implements IdSize {

    private Integer id;
    private BigDecimal size;
    @Override
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    @Override
    public BigDecimal getSize() {
        return size;
    }

}
```

Then you can make your method generic like this:

```
public <T extends IdSize> List<Comparator<T>> sort(Map<String, String> map) {
    List<Comparator<T>> list = new ArrayList<Comparator<T>>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        boolean sortOrder = entry.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("asc");
        Comparator<T> comparator = null;
        switch (entry.getKey()) {
            case "id":
                comparator = Comparator.comparing(IdSize::getId);
                break;
            case "size":
                comparator = Comparator.comparing(IdSize::getSize);
                break;
            default: // do something here, throw an exception?
        }
        list.add(sortOrder ? comparator : comparator.reversed());
    }
    return list;
}
```

(I refactored a little the switch-case statement to remove the duplicated code.). Also, you might want to add a default clause.

Comment: Alternatively, you could convert the method references `IdSize::getId` and `IdSize::getSize` to `Function` parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Use interfaces:

```
public interface Sizable {
    BigDecimal getSize();
}

public interface Id {
    int getId();
}
```

Have your classes implement those interface and use them in your generic methods:

```
public <T extends Id & Sizable> List<Comparator<T>> sort(Map<String, String> map) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably need something more dynamic. Some annotations may help

```
class Shoe

    @Column("id")
    @Sortable
    public int getId(){ ... }

    @Column("Description")
    public String getDescription(){...}
```

Given any class, you can reflect on columns to display, columns that can be sorted ("id",  ...), and values of columns (`"getId()"`, ...).

Comment: Data is not stored into a database in this case. They are instead stored into XML files (since they are almost static). The list is created based on XML files using JAXB :)

Comment: you can define metadata about these types in some other places... in any case, a more dynamic (and less safe statically) approach might be better.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a compound `Comparator` anyway, there is no point in filling a `List` first. Just do it in one operation:

```
public static <T> Comparator<T> getOrdering(
    Map<String, String> map, Map<String,Comparator<T>> defined) {

    return map.entrySet().stream().map(e -> {
        Comparator<T> c=defined.get(e.getKey());
        return e.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("asc")? c: c.reversed();
    })
    .reduce(Comparator::thenComparing)
    .orElseThrow(()->new IllegalArgumentException("empty"));
}
```

This works for arbitrary types but requires to provide a map of existing comparators for a type. But this `map` isn’t a restriction, it actually improves the operation as it removes the hardcoded set of existing named property comparators. You can use it with an arbitrary type, `Entity` being exemplary here, as follows:

```
Map<String,Comparator<Entity>> map=new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
map.put("id", Comparator.comparing(Entity::getID));
map.put("size", Comparator.comparing(Entity::getSize));

Comparator<Entity> cmp=getOrdering(param, map);
```

whereas `param` is the ordered map of your question, mapping from property name to either `"asc"` or `"desc"`. The `map` holding the predefined comparators can be created once in initialization code and then be re-used.

The creation code doesn’t look so complicated that it deserves implementing a dynamic solution, however, if you still wish to do it, here is the code to generate such a map for arbitrary classes:

```
public final class DynamicComparators<T> {
    public static <T> Map<String,Comparator<T>> getComparators(Class<T> cl) {
        return CACHE.get(cl).cast(cl).comps;
    }

    private static final ClassValue<DynamicComparators> CACHE
                         =new ClassValue<DynamicComparators>() {
        @Override protected DynamicComparators computeValue(Class<?> type) {
            return new DynamicComparators<>(type);
        }
    };
    private final Class<T> theClass;
    private final Map<String, Comparator<T>> comps;

    private DynamicComparators(Class<T> cl) {
        theClass=cl;
        Map<String,Comparator<T>> map=new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
        try {
            BeanInfo bi=Introspector.getBeanInfo(cl);
            MethodHandles.Lookup l=MethodHandles.lookup();
            MethodType invoked=MethodType.methodType(Function.class);
            for(PropertyDescriptor pd: bi.getPropertyDescriptors()) {
                Method m=pd.getReadMethod();
                if(m==null) continue;
                Class<?> t=m.getReturnType();
                if(!t.isPrimitive() && !Comparable.class.isAssignableFrom(t))
                    continue;
                MethodHandle mh=l.unreflect(m);
                MethodType mt=mh.type();
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")Comparator<T> cmp
                  = Comparator.comparing((Function<T,Comparable>)LambdaMetafactory
                    .metafactory(l, "apply", invoked, mt.generic(), mh, mt)
                    .getTarget().invokeExact());
                map.put(pd.getName(), cmp);
            }
        } catch(Throwable ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
        this.comps=Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") <U> DynamicComparators<U> cast(Class<U> cl) {
        if(cl!=theClass) throw new ClassCastException();
        return (DynamicComparators<U>)this;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see the loop is necessary in either case because ordering is purely based on the user's choice who interacts with the application. The list is displayed in a tabular structure like an [HTML table](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/sort.xhtml). Clicking column headers (holding a meta key for multiple sorting) passes either `asc` or `desc`. A user can perform sorting on any random field(s) in any order - it can be `id` and `size`, `size` and `id` or either of them (`id` or `size`).

Comment: But these comparators don’t provide any meaningful string representation that could be displayed. Thus, for the UI part you have to use the `Map<String,String>` anyway. If you have some sort of column header, you already have some sort of list of defined properties from which you could derive the second parameter of the `getOrdering` method…