# Streams Sorting by runtime parameter

Tags: java, sorting, reflection, collections, java-stream

I have custom Comparator `ChainedComparator`  and and it has multiple comparator in it, which will be passed at runtime.

```
class ChainedComparator implements Comparator<Person> {
    private List<Comparator<Person>> comparatorList;

    public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
        for (Comparator<Person> comparator : comparatorList) {
            int result = comparator.compare(o1, o2);
            if (result != 0) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return 0;

    }

    @SafeVarargs
    public ChainedComparator(Comparator<Person>... comparators) {
        this.comparatorList = Arrays.asList(comparators);
    }
}
```

now i want to create comparator at run time from the field name **age** , rather than hardcoding like below

```
Comparator<Person> ageComparator = Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge);
Comparator<Person> lastNameComparator = Comparator.comparing(Person::getLastName);
Comparator<Person> ageComparator = Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge);
personList.stream().sorted(new ChainedComparator(firstNameComparator,ageComparator))
```

any advice please

```
class Person {
    Person(){}
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    int age;
    String country;
    public Person( String firstName, String lastName, int age,String country) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
        this.country = country;

    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

Comment: It's a little unclear. Are you saying that you won't know the field to compare by until run time?

Comment: yes, I will get list of sorting fields  like age,firstName at runtime, and i want to create comparator at runtime and chain them

Comment: I can have switch or if clause to check field name and add corresponding comparator. but I want to be generic, where i pass the filed name , then it gets method reference and creates comparator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest, static way to do this may be to just maintain a field name -> Comparator map, like this:

```
private static Map<String, Comparator<Person>> comparatorMap = Map.of(
        "age", Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge),
        "firstName", Comparator.comparing(Person::getFirstName),
        "lastName", Comparator.comparing(Person::getLastName),
        "country", Comparator.comparing(Person::getCountry)
    );
```

Which, given a field list like

```
List<String> sortFields = Arrays.asList("age", "firstName", "lastName");
```

can be used to produce a composed comparator:

```
Optional<Comparator<Person>> chainedComparator = 
    sortFields.stream().map(comparatorMap::get).reduce(Comparator::thenComparing);

personList.stream().sorted(chainedComparator.get());
```

You can also notice that I used `Comparator`'s own `thenComparing` to compose comparators (instead of implementing it yourself).

---

Here's an *example* implementation using reflection to dynamically select the fields to sort by

Before it's used, note:
* It assumes that *fields* are of `Comparable` types (if you pass the name of a field whose type is not comparable, a class cast exception will be raised)
* I'm creating a comparator each time, you may want to store them against the field name, if that's necessary

```
private static Comparator<Person> personFieldComparator(String field) {
    return (person1, person2) -> readPersonField(person1, field)
            .compareTo(readPersonField(person2, field));
}

private static Comparable<Object> readPersonField(Person person, String field) {

    try {
        Field f = Person.class.getDeclaredField(field);
        f.setAccessible(true);

        return (Comparable<Object>) f.get(person);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
             | NoSuchFieldException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e); //proper handling needed
    }
}
```

And with that, you can change the initial implementation to something like:

```
Optional<Comparator<Person>> chainedComparator = sortFields.stream()
        .map(Main::personFieldComparator) //Main -> Your class name
        .reduce(Comparator::thenComparing);
personList.stream().sorted(chainedComparator.orElseThrow())...;
```

You may choose to extend this by using generics to make it not `Person`-specific

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there any way where we can generate this `Person::getAge`  at runtime, may be usingf reflection or other ways.

Comment: Of course one can use reflection, but I definitely preferred static, type-safe code. Have you perhaps looked into using a hash map instead of the class if you want dynamic access to fields?

Comment: Agreed. Static are better for type safety. Trying to understand how it can be created at run time something like `Comparator.comparing( new Person().getClass().getMethod("age")`. but not able to get the correct syntax

Comment: I can add an alternative using reflection if you need... Give me a moment

Comment: Look at the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33086888/2711488)…